# A round checkbox isn't working correctly on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I have some code which creates a 'round' checkbox effect.

It works fine on my desktop PC but on a mobile device unless you 'touch' in exactly the right place (at the bottom right-hand side) then the checkbox doesn't activate.

I just wondered if anyone knew how to make this code more robust in a mobile device or am I stuck using a media query to put a normal checkbox in for mobile users?

I have set up a [codePen](http://codepen.io/johnnyt/pen/XJLdme) here so you can see the effect.

The HTML is this:

```
<section title="JTroundCheckbox">
  <div class="JTroundCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1">
    <label for="checkbox1"></label>
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS is this:

```
.JTroundCheckbox {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.JTroundCheckbox label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px white;
}
.JTroundCheckbox label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.JTroundCheckbox label:hover::after {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.JTroundCheckbox input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.JTroundCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This is code that took from the net from [here.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles) (example labelled ROUNDED TWO in the code)

Many thanks for any light you can shed on this.

Comment: With the Element Inspector of your browser, be sure to check the position of the checkbox and if the label is working for this need, I've had similar problems with effects like this one and sometimes the solution has been to create a larger label.

Comment: Hi Zentaurus, I'll have a look at this when I get home tonight but I remember seeing the 'actual' checkbox as a very small dotted square at the bottom right-hand side of the main circle checkbox. So I'm guessing this is what is being relied on to be hit on a mobile. I'll experiment with a larger label and see what happens. Thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? http://codepen.io/nathanw/pen/PwrNLz

I removed the hidden attribute from the checkbox and positioned it directly 'underneath' the fancy checkbox. It seems to work fine on an iPad.

```
.JTroundCheckbox input[type=checkbox] {
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  position: relative;
  top:4px;
  left:4px;
}
```

Comment: = Genius! A massive thanks for that Nate. It's working loads better now. Cheers :-)